# Error with my sql statement syntax, please help!

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I have a synatx error

```
SELECT * `Orders` o
LEFT JOIN Shipment s 
ON  o.for_shipment_id  = s.shipment_id
WHERE 'internal_status' = 'HAS_SHIP_INFO' 
AND (s.ship_method = 'FEDEX' OR s.ship_method = 'USPS' OR s.ship_method = 'UPS')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `FROM` after your `*`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM   <-- You're missing this :o)
`Orders` oLEFT JOIN Shipment s ON  o.for_shipment_id  = s.shipment_idWHERE 'internal_status' = 'HAS_SHIP_INFO' AND (s.ship_method = 'FEDEX' OR s.ship_method = 'USPS' OR s.ship_method = 'UPS')
```